# On the calculus of the variable "autocov" from spdep package

Tags: coordinate-system, r, spatial-statistics, nearest-neighbor, spdep

I’m facing a spatial autocorrelation problem  and I want to calculate the «  autocov» covariate through the function `autocov_dist` from `spdep` package. The problem is when I defined the neighborhood radius as twice the minimum distance to the nearest neighbor `bw2`as follow :

```
library(spded)
        knn <- spdep::knn2nb(spdep::knearneigh(xy, k=1)) # xy are in UTM
        bw <- max(unlist(spdep::nbdists(knn, xy)))
        bw2 <- 2*min(unlist(spdep::nbdists(knn, xy)))
        AUTOCOV <- spdep::autocov_dist(Data_Species[,"P_A"], xy = xy, nbs = bw2, style = "B", type = "inverse")
```

I got this error message :

```
Error in nb2listw(nb, glist = gl, style = style, zero.policy = zero.policy) :   Empty neighbour sets foundDe plus : Warning message:In spdep::autocov_dist(Data_Species[, "P_A"], xy = xy, nbs = bw2,  :  With value 135.529724518632 some points have no neighbours
```

and I was obliged to use the maximum distance to the nearest neighbor `bw` to avoid this error but the radius here is too large. Is there any way how to manage the situation where some points have no neighbors.

Comment: Have you tried `zero.policy=TRUE`? This allows the weights list to contain zero-length weights vectors. Just keep in mind that you will still have empty neighbor sets.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, thank you, yes I tried to turn on the argument zero.policy and it works but I still have a problem when I plot the correlogram (I use ncf package). with small radius values, I get very large values of Moran's I statistic that exceed 1 or -1. So at this point what is the best choice of the neighborhood radius?

Comment: Honestly, you can obsess over the correct value and go down the rabbit hole but, in the outcome of the model rarely it is sensitive to the distance that the autocovariance function is defined at. I would say, find something that works and is justifiable and just go with it. Sometimes statistical modeling requires a degree of pragmatism.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, thank you for your explanations. I forgot something important that my data are not all from the same time period,  can I use the function autocov_dist but under a loop overtime where each time I recover xy of the corresponding year and extract the autocov and I recover the full vector as rbind?